# My Gmail business account not receiving email

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I'm not receiving any email to my Gmail business email account.

What reasons could this be for?

And what would I need to do to fix it?

(It is being sent.)

Recently my site was switched on to a different server. I don't know if that might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible issues are:

1. GMail or another mail server outage - nothing you can do.
2. Incorrect MX records. See the [detailed Google Help article](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33352) since the instructions depend on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a lot of reasons why emails from your other web based (alias) emails as in yourname@yourdomain.com isn't going through to your gmail account.
Here is what you need to do first before you do anything else:
Log into your gmail account go to the wheel and select Settings.
Go to Accounts and Import
Under 'Send mail as:'
Click on 'Add another email address you own'.  enter all of your aliases.
You have your default email here.. but you need to add all of your other addresses that you own that are forwarded to your main gmail account. On the right side you'll be able to edit and delete each of them.
got it?

Answer (score -2):

> Recently my site was switched on to a different server. I don't know
>   if that might be relevant.

Your question solved my problem!!

I was having the same issue, and I realised I just changed from Namecheap to DNSimple (It hadn't crossed my mind before). In my case, I just needed to set up everything properly in the new server.